# Getting Users webcam access automatically once user give permission

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I created a page with user video div using javascript. So once user give permission it will show user webcam on the corner of website. So what i am facing when i access any other pages again i need to ask for user permission. So is there any way to take user webcam access automatically once they give permission.

```
<div id="videoContainer">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
</div>
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
var next_button = document.getElementById("button_1");


if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true,video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      next_button.classList.remove("disabled");
      localStorage.setItem("camera_access", "granded");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        localStorage.setItem("camera_access", "declined");
    });
}
</script>
```

What I tried if user give permission I will save in local storage. But using this value I can't find a way to access webcam. Please give me some ideas.
**I think I can use ajax and load pages but that will be difficult because other pages are loading with parameters and all.**